# Why doesn't React automatically allow child components to call setState of the parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying a child component to setState to the parent component, but it not working in `reactjs`.

Comment: Here at StackOverflow, we can also answer the question ourselves for knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React, and the Flux pattern (that helps manage complex application with multiple React components) espouse uni-directional data flow. **Uni-directional data flow** makes an application easy to reason, and debug because:

- If there is something wrong with a React component, you trace upwards to the parent recursively until you find the root cause, because the data flow/setState could have only come upstream

Child React components do indirectly setState of parent but only through notifying parents about certain events, e.g., a mouse click. The parent itself then decides if the mouse click should trigger setState of its own state, which is passed down as props to its children.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    const _childValue = this.state.childValue; 
    this.setState({ childValue: _childValue + 1 });
  } 
  render() {
    return (<ChildComponent value={this.state.childVvalue} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />)
  } 
} 
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span> 
        <div>My value: {this.props.value} </div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Increment</button> 
      </span> 
    ) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Glad you found my answer helpful.